# How to convert version number to integer value?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert application version numbers such as 5.3.0.1 (Android) and 5.3.0 (iOS) to integers in Python. The function should give output value as 5301 for Android and 530 for iOS.

I have written the following code but looking to make it smaller and better:

```
version = "5.3.0"
num = (version).split('.')

for i in num:
    version += i

print version
```

Suggest me some better options!

Comment: `int("".join(version.split(",")))`

Comment: `int(''.join(version.split('.')))` don't forget to actually make it a number.

Comment: Be careful...if any of the components can be > 9, your conversion can lead to ambiguity, e.g. is `5100` equivalent to `5.10.0` or `5.1.0.0`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You're assuming OP needs to represent the integers in base 10. ;) (which is a very valid assumption, I'm just being facetious)

Comment: I'd definitely recommend your solution allows for components of the version to be 10 or greater.  It's awfully common.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps something a little more direct:

```
major, minor, patch = [int(x, 10) for x in version.split('.')]
```

The above will give you each component of the version number.  You could also do something like:

```
l = [int(x, 10) for x in version.split('.')]
l.reverse()
version = sum(x * (100 ** i) for i, x in enumerate(l))
```

This will allow each component of the version number to vary between 0 and 99 (instead of just 0 through 9).  It's a fairly common practice in C for recording version numbers.

If you really only want to handle components of the version being in the 0 to 9 range, simply change the 100 to a 10:

```
l = [int(x, 10) for x in version.split('.')]
l.reverse()
version = sum(x * (10 ** i) for i, x in enumerate(l))
```

Comment: I still think this is more of a complex algorithm. I like using replace :) Nice job though

Comment: Well, it's a slightly different solution than what the OP asked for.  Here you get each component individually instead of all combined into a single integer--at least the first solution I offered.  Thanks for the kudos though. :-)

Comment: separating the components out is the **right** way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

If you have some version in the following format:

```
<major>.<minor>.<tiny>.<build_number>
```

for example:

```
2.12.0.1234
```

and you want to convert this version into integer value to be able to store it as int value or to be able to compare two versions easily, you can use this code:

```
def int_to_version(val):
    major = (val & 0xFF000000) >> 24
    minor = (val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16
    tiny = (val & 0x0000F000) >> 12
    build = (val & 0x00000FFF)
    return f"{major}.{minor}.{tiny}.{build}"


def version_to_int(version):
    major, minor, tiny, build = map(int, version.split("."))
    major = (major << 24) & 0xFF000000
    minor = (minor << 16) & 0x00FF0000
    tiny = (tiny << 12) & 0x0000F000
    build = build & 0x00000FFF
    return int(major | minor | tiny | build)


# poc
ver = "2.12.0.1234"

print(version_to_int(ver))                          # 34342098
print(int_to_version(version_to_int(ver)))          # "2.12.0.1234"

# use version_to_int() to compare versions
ver1 = "2.12.0.1234"
ver2 = "2.12.1.1237"
print(version_to_int(ver2) > version_to_int(ver1))  # True

ver3 = "3.0.1.3456"
print(version_to_int(ver3) > version_to_int(ver2))  # True
print(version_to_int(ver3) < version_to_int(ver1))  # False
```

That's it!

Comment: When e.g. a build section is missing it errors out, I had to add an if check

Comment: @wamae yes, my solution is just an example that doesn't contain a validation code since it's always specific thing for each particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
int(''.join(x for x in version.split('.')))
```

Comment: `x for x in` doesn't add anything to the solution... `ver.split(".") == list(x for x in ver.split("."))` is `True`

Comment: ...and `''.join(version.split('.'))` is equal to `version.replace('.', '')`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I am still relatively new to Python. @TemporalWolf

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be simply

```
version = "5.3.0"
int(version.replace(".", ""))
```

This would give you `530`

However, if version starts with 0, for example `version = 0.1.1`, you should simply do

```
version.replace(".", "")
```

to avoid losing the 0 in front.

Comment: This is not an integer, but a string.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a fairly simple generator expression:

```
>>> version = "5.3.0"
>>> int(''.join(c for c in version if c != '.'))
530
>>>
```

Or, you can simply use `.split()` and save yourself a step:

```
>>> version = "5.3.0"
>>> int(''.join(version.split(".")))
530
>>>
```

---

In case performance matters, here are the timings for the various methods compiled from the different answers:

```
Method: int(version.replace(".", ""))
Time: 0.4673201900150161
---------
Method: int(''.join(x for x in version.split('.')))
Time: 1.2946192430099472
---------
Method: int(''.join(c for c in version if c != '.'))
Time: 1.248846340982709
---------
Method: int(''.join(version.split(".")))
Time: 0.5846817549900152
---------
Method: [int(x, 10) for x in version.split('.')]
Time: 1.2502875960199162
```

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not endorsing, taking credit for, or recommending any of the solutions above. Credit is due to the original authors. The purpose of the above chart, is to give the OP a fairly accurate measurement of the performance of each method.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2<sup>1</sup>, use the `translate` method:

```
version = "5.3.0"
print "Prior:",version
version = int(version.translate(None, '.'))
print "After:",version
```

Which gives:

```
Prior: 5.3.0
After: 530
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In `Python3,` the comparable script would be:

```
version = "5.3.0"
print("Prior:",version)
version = int(version.translate({ord('.'): None}))
print("After:",version)
```

Comment: Does not work reliably when the parts can exceed 9, e.g. "5.0.11" (5011) > "5.1.0" (510)